# Making class templated forces repeating base class template params in inheriting constructor

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++14, clang++

I recently changed a class from being templated to not, and discovered that I can no longer omit template arguments when writing a using declaration to inherit a constructor from a templated base class. As long as my class isn't templated I can omit the arguments, as soon as it is I can't. In the compilable snippet below `bar` represents the class before and `buzz` represents the class after. I've tested both GCC 5.2 and Clang 3.7 and they have the same behavior. Is this a compiler bug or standard?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class B>
struct foo {
    foo(int x) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

struct bar : foo<bar, short> {
    using foo::foo; // this appears legal
    // using foo<bar, short>::foo; // this works too, thought I would need it
};

template<class X>
struct buzz : foo<buzz<X>, short> {
     //using foo::foo; // no longer legal for some reason
    using foo<buzz<X>, short>::foo; // now do actually need this
};

int main() {
    bar x(3);
    buzz<float> y(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard.

> `N4140 [temp.dep]/3:` In the definition of a class or class template, if a base class depends on a template-parameter, the base class
>   scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template
>   or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

For `buzz`, the base class depends on a template parameter, so the `foo` unqualified lookup does not examine its scope. That is why you need qualified lookup.